# C++ Adding File Permissions to Zip File

Tags: c++, zip, file-permissions, zlib

I'm working on a zipping program in C++. I would like to add the security descriptor so that my file permissions are preserved when zipping. I am using Zlib's Minizip to zip up the files and I am aware that Minizip does not have the capability of saving file permissions. I think that I may have to add the security descriptions manually to the extra field.

How do I get the security permissions of a file?

How do I format the Security Descriptor for a zip file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Info-ZIP's zip and unzip](http://www.info-zip.org/) utilities.  They provide much more extensive support for various operating systems than the base minizip functionality.

For doing it yourself, you can refer to the [Info-ZIP appnote](http://www.info-zip.org/doc/appnote-20040908-iz.zip).  The Windows extra field is defined in there, copied here:

```
         -PKWARE Win95/WinNT Extra Field (0x000a):
          =======================================

          The following description covers PKWARE's "NTFS" attributes
          "extra" block, introduced with the release of PKZIP 2.50 for
          Windows. (Last Revision 20001118)

          (Note: At this time the Mtime, Atime and Ctime values may
          be used on any WIN32 system.)
         [Info-ZIP note: In the current implementations, this field has
          a fixed total data size of 32 bytes and is only stored as local
          extra field.]

          Value         Size        Description
          -----         ----        -----------
  (NTFS)  0x000a        Short       Tag for this "extra" block type
          TSize         Short       Total Data Size for this block
          Reserved      Long        for future use
          Tag1          Short       NTFS attribute tag value #1
          Size1         Short       Size of attribute #1, in bytes
          (var.)        SubSize1    Attribute #1 data
          .
          .
          .
          TagN          Short       NTFS attribute tag value #N
          SizeN         Short       Size of attribute #N, in bytes
          (var.)        SubSizeN    Attribute #N data

          For NTFS, values for Tag1 through TagN are as follows:
          (currently only one set of attributes is defined for NTFS)

          Tag        Size       Description
          -----      ----       -----------
          0x0001     2 bytes    Tag for attribute #1
          Size1      2 bytes    Size of attribute #1, in bytes (24)
          Mtime      8 bytes    64-bit NTFS file last modification time
          Atime      8 bytes    64-bit NTFS file last access time
          Ctime      8 bytes    64-bit NTFS file creation time

          The total length for this block is 28 bytes, resulting in a
          fixed size value of 32 for the TSize field of the NTFS block.

          The NTFS filetimes are 64-bit unsigned integers, stored in Intel
          (least significant byte first) byte order. They determine the
          number of 1.0E-07 seconds (1/10th microseconds!) past WinNT "epoch",
          which is "01-Jan-1601 00:00:00 UTC".
```

Comment: Thanks, we actually changed our code from previously using Info-Zip to now using Minizip because we needed zip64 support. But if you could give me some idea of how to get the permissions manually I think that I can just add them to the extra data fields myself.

Comment: Or if you could add zip64 support to Info-Zip that would be great! :)

Comment: On what sort of system are you trying to preserve the permission attributes?